# Recycle View Inside Of Fragment Not Calling OnViewCreate

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

So basically, it's as the title says. I'm implementing a recycle view inside a fragment to create a map on one part of the screen. I need two recycle views on the page but only one isn't working. When I run the debugger in Android Studio it never reaches the override methods in the Adapter class. Below is the code, unfortunately it's a lot.
I should also mention

- Number of items is caclulated and is not zero
- Adapter is added to recycler view
- Layout manager is added to recycler view

Why aren't any of the overriden methods being called?
Please let me know if you require further information

FRAGMENT

```
     public class FragmentMap extends Fragment {
    
        // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
        private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
        private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    
        private String mParam1;
        private String mParam2;
    
        MapData mapData;
        StructureData structures;
        public FragmentMap(MapData mapData, StructureData structures)
        {
            this.mapData = mapData;
            this.structures = structures;
        }
    
        public FragmentMap() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

    public static FragmentMap newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentMap fragment = new FragmentMap();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        RecyclerView rv = view.findViewById(R.id.mapRecyclerView);
        SelectorAdapter myAdapter = new SelectorAdapter(structures);
        MapAdapter mapAdapter = new MapAdapter(mapData);
        rv.setAdapter(mapAdapter);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(
                getActivity(),
                MapData.HEIGHT,
                GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,
                false));

        return view;
    }
}
```

ADAPTER

```
public class MapAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MapViewHolder>{

    MapData mapData;

    public MapAdapter(MapData mapData)
    {
        this.mapData = mapData;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MapViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_cell,parent,false);
        MapViewHolder myViewHolder = new MapViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MapViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int row = position % MapData.HEIGHT;
        int col = position / MapData.HEIGHT;
        MapElement mapElement = mapData.get(row, col);

        holder.cellOne.setImageResource(mapElement.getNorthEast());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d("TAG", "getItemCount: " + MapData.HEIGHT * MapData.WIDTH);
        return MapData.HEIGHT * MapData.WIDTH;
    }
}
```

VIEWHOLDER

```
public class MapViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView cellOne, cellTwo, cellThree, cellFour, structure;
    ConstraintLayout parent;

    public MapViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cellOne = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageOne);
        cellTwo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageTwo);
        cellThree = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageThree);
        cellFour = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageFour);

        parent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent);
        int size = parent.getMeasuredHeight() / MapData.HEIGHT + 1;
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = itemView.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = size;
        lp.height = size;
    }
}
```

MAPDATA

```
public class MapData
{
    public static final int WIDTH = 30;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 10;

    private static final int WATER = R.drawable.ic_water;
    private static final int[] GRASS = {R.drawable.ic_grass1, R.drawable.ic_grass2,
            R.drawable.ic_grass3, R.drawable.ic_grass4};

    private static final Random rng = new Random();
    private MapElement[][] grid;

    private static MapData instance = null;

    public static MapData get()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new MapData(generateGrid());
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private static MapElement[][] generateGrid()
    {
        final int HEIGHT_RANGE = 256;
        final int WATER_LEVEL = 112;
        final int INLAND_BIAS = 24;
        final int AREA_SIZE = 1;
        final int SMOOTHING_ITERATIONS = 2;

        int[][] heightField = new int[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
        for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
            {
                heightField[i][j] =
                    rng.nextInt(HEIGHT_RANGE)
                    + INLAND_BIAS * (
                        Math.min(Math.min(i, j), Math.min(HEIGHT - i - 1, WIDTH - j - 1)) -
                        Math.min(HEIGHT, WIDTH) / 4);
            }
        }

        int[][] newHf = new int[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
        for(int s = 0; s < SMOOTHING_ITERATIONS; s++)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
                {
                    int areaSize = 0;
                    int heightSum = 0;

                    for(int areaI = Math.max(0, i - AREA_SIZE);
                            areaI < Math.min(HEIGHT, i + AREA_SIZE + 1);
                            areaI++)
                    {
                        for(int areaJ = Math.max(0, j - AREA_SIZE);
                                areaJ < Math.min(WIDTH, j + AREA_SIZE + 1);
                                areaJ++)
                        {
                            areaSize++;
                            heightSum += heightField[areaI][areaJ];
                        }
                    }

                    newHf[i][j] = heightSum / areaSize;
                }
            }

            int[][] tmpHf = heightField;
            heightField = newHf;
            newHf = tmpHf;
        }

        MapElement[][] grid = new MapElement[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
        for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
            {
                MapElement element;

                if(heightField[i][j] >= WATER_LEVEL)
                {
                    boolean waterN = (i == 0)          || (heightField[i - 1][j] < WATER_LEVEL);
                    boolean waterE = (j == WIDTH - 1)  || (heightField[i][j + 1] < WATER_LEVEL);
                    boolean waterS = (i == HEIGHT - 1) || (heightField[i + 1][j] < WATER_LEVEL);
                    boolean waterW = (j == 0)          || (heightField[i][j - 1] < WATER_LEVEL);

                    boolean waterNW = (i == 0) ||          (j == 0) ||         (heightField[i - 1][j - 1] < WATER_LEVEL);
                    boolean waterNE = (i == 0) ||          (j == WIDTH - 1) || (heightField[i - 1][j + 1] < WATER_LEVEL);
                    boolean waterSW = (i == HEIGHT - 1) || (j == 0) ||         (heightField[i + 1][j - 1] < WATER_LEVEL);
                    boolean waterSE = (i == HEIGHT - 1) || (j == WIDTH - 1) || (heightField[i + 1][j + 1] < WATER_LEVEL);

                    boolean coast = waterN || waterE || waterS || waterW ||
                                    waterNW || waterNE || waterSW || waterSE;

                    grid[i][j] = new MapElement(
                        !coast,
                        choose(waterN, waterW, waterNW,
                            R.drawable.ic_coast_north, R.drawable.ic_coast_west,
                            R.drawable.ic_coast_northwest, R.drawable.ic_coast_northwest_concave),
                        choose(waterN, waterE, waterNE,
                            R.drawable.ic_coast_north, R.drawable.ic_coast_east,
                            R.drawable.ic_coast_northeast, R.drawable.ic_coast_northeast_concave),
                        choose(waterS, waterW, waterSW,
                            R.drawable.ic_coast_south, R.drawable.ic_coast_west,
                            R.drawable.ic_coast_southwest, R.drawable.ic_coast_southwest_concave),
                        choose(waterS, waterE, waterSE,
                            R.drawable.ic_coast_south, R.drawable.ic_coast_east,
                            R.drawable.ic_coast_southeast, R.drawable.ic_coast_southeast_concave),
                        null);
                }
                else
                {
                    grid[i][j] = new MapElement(
                        false, WATER, WATER, WATER, WATER, null);
                }
            }
        }
        return grid;
    }

    private static int choose(boolean nsWater, boolean ewWater, boolean diagWater,
        int nsCoastId, int ewCoastId, int convexCoastId, int concaveCoastId)
    {
        int id;
        if(nsWater)
        {
            if(ewWater)
            {
                id = convexCoastId;
            }
            else
            {
                id = nsCoastId;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(ewWater)
            {
                id = ewCoastId;
            }
            else if(diagWater)
            {
                id = concaveCoastId;
            }
            else
            {
                id = GRASS[rng.nextInt(GRASS.length)];
            }
        }
        return id;
    }

    protected MapData(MapElement[][] grid)
    {
        this.grid = grid;
    }

    public void regenerate()
    {
        this.grid = generateGrid();
    }

    public MapElement get(int i, int j)
    {
        return grid[i][j];
    }
}
```

MAP ELEMENT

```
public class MapElement
{
    private final boolean buildable;
    private final int terrainNorthWest;
    private final int terrainSouthWest;
    private final int terrainNorthEast;
    private final int terrainSouthEast;
    private Structure structure;

    public MapElement(boolean buildable, int northWest, int northEast,
                      int southWest, int southEast, Structure structure)
    {
        this.buildable = buildable;
        this.terrainNorthWest = northWest;
        this.terrainNorthEast = northEast;
        this.terrainSouthWest = southWest;
        this.terrainSouthEast = southEast;
        this.structure = structure;
    }

    public boolean isBuildable()
    {
        return buildable;
    }

    public int getNorthWest()
    {
        return terrainNorthWest;
    }

    public int getSouthWest()
    {
        return terrainSouthWest;
    }

    public int getNorthEast()
    {
        return terrainNorthEast;
    }

    public int getSouthEast()
    {
        return terrainSouthEast;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the structure built on this map element.
     * @return The structure, or null if one is not present.
     */
    public Structure getStructure()
    {
        return structure;
    }

    public void setStructure(Structure structure)
    {
        this.structure = structure;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing only one RecyclerView in onCreateView, if you want to have two Recyclerviews you just need to initialize second one in the same way.

Comment: The other is created in a separate fragment that I didn't include because it works.

Comment: I would check if data parsed to adapter are not empty, but you propably did that